# MFP-Cli (MobileFirst Platform 7.1) on MacOS El Capitan

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

I just updated my MacOS to El Capitan and I tried to install the newest MFP-Cli, version 7.1, on it but no success.

When I double click on **install_mac.app** the password screen shows up, but after that it closes without message.

I also tried to run the **install** file inside of install_mac.app/ and I got the following:

> 2015-10-06 11:06:54.828 install[991:10602] Exe: /Users/jairrillo/Downloads/mobilefirst-cli-installer-7.1.0/install_mac.app/Contents/Resources/install.app
>   logout
>   Saving session...
>   ...copying shared history...
>   ...saving history...truncating history files...
>   ...completed.

Does anyone had the same issue?

Comment: FYI, I've had similar issues in the past with this installer: http://ift.tt/1Njl7YU.

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to OS X El Capitan.

The installation fails due to a bug in the product that has been resolved.
Look out for a newer build to be released, soon. Its build number should be 7.1.0.0 ... IF201510051721.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be caused by a missing or misconfigured JDK. I seemed to run into this issue despite not recalling a JDK uninstall since last using MFP-CLI 7.1, so it is possible an El Capitan update may have done something to your JDK 7 install. Run a quick "java" command in your Terminal and it should alert you to JDK issues if that is the case.